# Java - Library path error

Tags: java, path

I'm trying to start my java game but I have some troubles with the java command line:

Here is what I type:

`C:\>java -Djava.library.path=%cd%\lib -jar game.jar`

And here is what I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
    at com.game.Main.main(Main.java:7)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I can start my game with Eclipse (With Run as Java Application) but after the menu I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:65)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:81)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:98)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:129)
    at com.game.displaygui.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`lwjgl.jar` has been put into the folder `\lib`.

Could you explain me with I got that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This because lwjgl library is made by two components:

- the **.jar** file which contains Java code
- and the native binary library (which can be **.so** or **.dll** or **.dylib** according to your OS)

The first error you are getting is because you are setting the library path, that should contain the *native* library, but it does contain the .jar. So you get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` because you should set either the library path to the folder that contains native library, either the classpath to contain the real *lwjgl.jar* file.

The second error that you get with Eclipse is a successive step: your classpath contains the jar library but it is not able to find the native library attached to it, you can fix it in the following way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should specify explicitly which lib files to include (seperated by ;) :

```
-cp %cd%\lib\lwjdl.jar;%cd%\lib\<another-lib>.jar
```

Don't be tempted to use the wildcard * as it will cause more harm than good (from previous experience :))

Answer (score 0):

You use the `java.library.path` option to specify the location of native libraries to load. In the location pointed to by that option you would place all `dll` or `.so` files required by LWJGL. On the other hand, you need to make sure that all required JAR files are on your classpath, via the `-classpath` option. Currently, you have your JAR files in the wrong directory.

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to do here?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, if you using maven.

Add the following to the project "Run" : "VM options" .

```
-Djava.library.path=yourpath/youproject/java/target/natives
```