# Export jar file in Eclipse with libraries

Tags: java, exception, lwjgl

So after all those days I finally finished my work for school, but I need to export it to a jar file. My project includes for example LWJGL. I think he finds it, but I get this Exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException

and so on.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063530/java-library-path-error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it. Someone told me to add this line to my source code:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("native").getAbsolutePath());
```

and it works after I created the "native" folder in my projects folder.

New problem any way is, that my text is only drawn, if I start my program with command line

Answer (score 0):

When you are exporting your jar file 
Tick the check-box of
export generated class files and resources and also 
export Java source files and resources 
Then, you should have all the source files.