# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException

Tags: java, lwjgl, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, slick2d

Trying to work on a game for school and I keep getting a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException" when trying to run using eclipse. Any ideas? Here is my code

```
package javagame;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;


public class Game extends StateBasedGame{

private static final String GAME_NAME = "TEST";
private static final int MENU = 0;
private static final int PLAY = 1;

public Game(String GAME_NAME){
    super(GAME_NAME);
    this.addState(new Menu(MENU));
    this.addState(new Play(PLAY));
}// end constructor

public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException{
    this.getState(MENU).init(gc, this);
    this.getState(PLAY).init(gc, this);
    this.enterState(MENU);
}//end initStateList method

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AppGameContainer appgc;
    try{
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(GAME_NAME));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(640, 360, false);
        appgc.start();
    }//end try
    catch(SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//end catch

}//end main method

}//end Game class
```

And the full error I am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
at javagame.Game.main(Game.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

And I'm pretty sure I have this set correct.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS6Do.png

Comment: Is it the lwjgl jar exported in the 'Order and Export' tab?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking, but this is my Order and Export tab
http://i.imgur.com/nCaBAmG.png

Comment: Have you set the right natives?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063530/java-library-path-error

Comment: I found that page and tried everything on it before I posted here, sorry I should have said that. And I do have the windows natives set as I am running on a windows machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out so I will post it in case anyone else having the same problem stumbles upon this page. I had to use an older version of lwjgl.jar, version 2.9.3 worked from the old lwjgl website http://legacy.lwjgl.org/ .

Comment: I'm still curious as to why it did not work in the first place.