# Why do I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException" error?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, lwjgl, noclassdeffounderror

I am using Java version 1.8, and I use lwjgl version 2.9.3. I tried the below code by following a YouTube tutorial to setup OpenGl in Java. Below is the code,

```
    package renderEngin;

    import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;

    public class DisplayManager 
    {
        private static final int WIDTH = 1366;
        private static final int HEIGHT = 768;
        private static final int FPS_MAX = 120;

        public static void createDisplay() 
        {
            ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2);
            attribs.withForwardCompatible(true);
            attribs.withProfileCore(true);
            try
            {
                Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
                Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
                Display.setTitle("Jigoku");
            }
            catch (LWJGLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        }

        public static void updateDisplay() 
        {
            Display.sync(FPS_MAX);
            Display.update();
        }

        public static void closeDisplay() 
        {   
            Display.destroy();
        }
    }
```

and the main function in,

```
package enginTester;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import renderEngin.DisplayManager;

public class MainGameLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DisplayManager.createDisplay();
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
        }

        DisplayManager.closeDisplay();

    }

}
```

This question may seem like a dumb one, but I am still a rookie in Java and I have no idea where I am going wrong. Also I have searched the web but none of the answers seem to work. Someone answered to change the lwjgl version and so I changed it from 2.9.1 to 2.9.3 but it does not seem to work. 
Also I use eclipse IDE for the project.
Please help me.

Comment: What are you using for dependency injection ?

Comment: @SuhasNM Sorry, I can't understand what is "dependency injection" is. Sorry!

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: @SuhasNm No, I am not using Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post could help: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334257/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-lwjgl-lwjglexception)

Try to use a newer version of java, or even switch to lwjgl3(I know i answered late and you probably solved
the issue)

edit: If you switch to LWJGL3 here is a book that might help: https://lwjglgamedev.gitbooks.io/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/content/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.